# Transparent Toolbar with Fading color

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar

I would like to have a transparent/translucent `toolbar` in my app, just like this one here:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

activity_activity_profil.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.appmac.ron.app_newsfeed.ActivityProfil">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_color"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@null"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_activity_profil" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

toolbar_color.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#4f000000"
        android:endColor="#a8000000"
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

I spent many hours searching for a suitable solution, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I search in web and finally this layout its works.
with material effect.

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/appbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="235dp"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

      <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

          <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_top"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:animationCache="false"
            android:animationDuration="500"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/main" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#25ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```